# Switch between production and sandbox environment with haskell stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm working on a haskell application that calls a web service. I'd like that when building with `stack build` the application targets the URL of the real production server but that when debugging with `stack repl` the application targets the URL of a test server.

I guess this can be achieved with conditional compilation, but how do I configure stack to pass an option such as `-DDEBUG=1` to GHCi but not to GHC?

More generally speaking, many tools (Visual Studio, Xcode…) support multiple build configurations for a project. Is there a stack or cabal equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to check at runtime if [`System.Environment.getProgName`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-9.8/base-4.9.1.0/System-Environment.html#v:getProgName) is `ghc`.  This is not necessarily a reliable check, because the executable could in some cases be called something else.  It will be `ghc` for stack installed executables, but for system installed ghcs it might very well be `ghc-8.0.1` or something.  So, this approach is not all that reliable.

A better approach has occurred to me, which is to add a `.ghci` file, which contains commands for ghci to run on startup. I haven't tested this, but I think it would work to put `:set -DDEBUG=1` in `.ghci` in your project root.  Will also need to tweak its permissions with `chmod go-w .ghci`.

Comment: I didn't know about `.ghci` files. I just tried your suggestion and it works. Thank you very much!